# SQL - Why does my output from subqueries display my answer multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The output to the following query is repeated for the number of rows in my table. Can anyone explain why and if using 'Limit 1' to solve this is a good habit to get into?

```
SELECT

CAST((SELECT COUNT(event_id)
FROM creation_funnel
WHERE Ds = 2018-10-01 AND action = "publish") AS float) / 

CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT event_id)
FROM creation_funnel
WHERE Ds = 2018-10-01) AS float)
 * 100.0

FROM creation_funnel;
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks strange to me, that you are using aggregation function *Count* without the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: Try removing the `FROM creation_funnel` at the end

Comment: 2018-10-01 = 2007

Answer (score 2):

This query would be a good candidate for conditional aggregation as it will enable you to get rid of the two subqueries. Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Ds = '2018-10-01' AND action = 'publish' THEN event_id END) /
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Ds = '2018-10-01' THEN event_id END) * 100 AS percent_published
FROM creation_funnel
```

Note that date strings need to be enclosed in quotes, as @Strawberry points out, 2018-10-01 is interpreted as an integer expression, evaluating to 2007.

This query will also only give you one result compared to your query, which will give you a result for every row in the table. Either removing the `FROM` clause, or adding `LIMIT 1` would resolve that, but using conditional aggregation is a better alternative.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
CAST((SELECT COUNT(event_id) FROM creation_funnel WHERE Ds = '2018-10-01' AND action = "publish") AS float) /
CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) FROM creation_funnel WHERE Ds = '2018-10-01') AS float) * 100.0
```

The repetition is because of the FROM part of the statement. Remove it. 
Your are getting multiple results because the select is being run for each record in the table.

**updated**

Based on what nick said. You could simplify his answer to the following.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'publish' THEN event_id ELSE 0 END) / 
    COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) * 100 AS percent_published
FROM creation_funnel
WHERE Ds = '2018-10-01';
```